# Spring Boot JPA with Neo4j and multiple nodes

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I have created a small Spring Boot Project that takes data from a local neo4j data source ( ogm ) and hopefully will return weather data from DarkSky / OpenWeather along with later collected data from my homebrew weather station,

So the setup are 3 node entities

WeatherData
DarkSky
OpenWeather

My Cypher query inside the WeatherDataRepository looks like this,

```
@Query("Match (z:Zone),(w:WeatherData),(c:Customer),(d:DarkSky),(o:OpenWeather) where 
    c.ID_Token = $token" + " and (c)-[:Has_Subscribed_To]->(z) and (z)<-[:Weather_Data_For]-(w) return w as WeatherData, d "+ "as DarkSky, o as OpenWeather")
```

**List weather(String token);**

In the webUI the query returns the 3 nodes and relationships according to the matching of each part.

So ive tried a few things inside the controller after reading from docs.spring.io around this area but have not achieved what I am looking for so obviously doing it wrong.

my current WeatherData Controller looks like,

```
@NodeEntity(label = "WeatherData")
public class WeatherData {
      
private String Description;
private List<DarkSky> DarkSky;
private List<OpenWeather> OpenWeather;
      
public List<DarkSky> getDarkSky() {
    return DarkSky;
}
    
public void setDarkSky(List<DarkSky> darkSky) {
    DarkSky = darkSky;
}
    
public List<OpenWeather> getOpenWeather() {
    return OpenWeather;
}
    
public void setOpenWeather(List<OpenWeather> openWeather) {
    OpenWeather = openWeather;
}
    
public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}
      
public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}
```

I have autowired the repository, so with this I am getting the description from the WeatherData Node but not the DarkSky or OpenWeather Nodes.  From Postman I get the following

```
[
    {
        "description": "Weather Data From DarkSky And OpenWeather",
        "darkSky": null,
        "openWeather": null
    }
]
```

as you can see,  any help here would be more than appreciated as I am still learning alot about the framework and methods on getting the data in I require.